# Philips Monitor problems - vertical lines on screen

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I have an old CRT Philips Monitor 17'' and it was working well.

There were problems with the electrical power and the monitor started to make some sound and a smoke was getting out of it. I quickly switched it off the power, and in the morning when the power was ok i started the monitor and it appeared to be working and it worked for a couple of minutes when i find out some smell was coming from it, and after 5 minutes the screen i was working shut down and on the monitor some vertical lines appeared - and nothing else. I thought it was the OS, so i rebooted the pc and while it was booting i realized the monitor didn't show the bios info etc, but the same vertical lines on the whole screen were on it, sometimes their color was changing and they were blinking, but no screen appeared - only those vertical lines.

After a day, the monitor was ok again - i turned it on and no there were no lines, everything was working fine. The same for the next 2 days.

My question is: If anyone had ever had the same problem, can you help me ? THe monitor may be ok now but i am afraid it can get back those lines again. I don't know what to do, if you know please tell me whether should i take it to the service or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"Sound and smoke" is not good. The monitor may be a fire hazard and I strongly recommend that you do not use it further. It sounds like a short somewhere, possibly in the circuitry that controls the direction of the electron beam.

As the problem is intermittent it may be due to a lose connection and/or be thermally sensitive (i.e. the problem will appear when some part of the device approaches a certain temperature).

Comment: This! Do not use it! Get it checked out by a technician, or buy a new one(or get one from a friend. Most people give them away now)